# asp.net onclick function is not working for a tag

Tags: asp.net

I have this aspx code

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1" >Today</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-2" runat="server" onclick="TodayTab_Click">Tomorrow</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-3">Any Date</a></li>
```

although i have used `onclick` function, this function is not being fired,

why please?7

#### this is the function and I make a break point on it

```
protected void TodayTab_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            int i = 9;
            i++;
        }
```

#### edit2

You guys told me that I have to change my `a` tag to `asp:Hyperlink` and I did, but the function is still not being fired.

and this is the updated code

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1" >Today</a></li>
                <li><asp:Hyperlink href="#tabs-2" runat="server" onclick="TodayTab_Click">Tomorrow</asp:Hyperlink></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-3">Any Date</a></li>
```

Comment: post your function too!

Comment: This is a HTML onclick handler, therefore looking for a **client script `TodayTab_Click` function**. Server code functions can only be wired to *ASP.NET Web Forms server controls* (typically `<asp:TextBox>` or a different prefix), which are rendered to some **JavaScript code that actually posts a request back to the server**, which in turn invokes the handler. `TodayTab_Click`'s name looks like a server side method to me (but this is only a guess I admit)...

Comment: @MatthiasMeid thanks for the information, i changed my `a` to `asp:Hyperlink` and still that function is not being fired

Comment: @user3432257 Could you update the code?

Comment: @MatthiasMeid I just did

Comment: Use a `<asp:LinkButton>` instead of `<asp:Hyperlink>` - that will work with the `OnClick` event handler

Comment: @freefaller I tried it and still not work

Comment: @user "it doesn't work" is the most unhelpful thing you can say - give me more details - what is it doing, what should it be doing?

Comment: @freefaller sorry you right, i make a break point on that function. but when I used your solution and click on the link, the visual studio didn't stop the execting on that break point

Answer (score 3):

You should use a `<asp:LinkButton>` control - this is instead of `<a runat="server">` or `<asp:HyperLink>`.

The `<asp:LinkButton>` will use the `OnClick` event handler as per your requirement.

(As a side note, if you need to do any client-side processing, use the `OnClientClick` attribute to generate the `onclick` attribute on the rendered control)

Here's what that would end up looking like:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" onclick="TodayTab_Click" Text="Tomorrow" />
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I make a breakpoint on that function but that function is not being fired, please help

Comment: Is the page actually posting back when you click on the link?

Comment: how could I know please? I make a function so when i press the link, that function should be fired. let me tell you why i need that, maybe you have a better solutoin, i have three taps, which are divs, I want to know which tag is selected now. can you help please? in addition, this is just a single page. can i give you the whole code please?

Comment: If you're going to code in ASP.NET it is essential that you understand the [page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).  Asking how to tell if the page is being posted-back indicates that you simply don't have a good enough knowledge of how ASP.NET works

Comment: I need to be away for the next 45 minutes... if I don't reply, that is why

Comment: please when you come back tell me. and I do know lettle thing about post back but I can for 100% percent tell you that the page is not going post back

Comment: If it's not posting back, it is never going to break-point the code. You need to figure out (using browser developer tools F12) why that is the case

Answer (score 0):

You need to use onServerClick function instead of onClick

```
onServerClick="TodayTab_Click"
```

Comment: This is the code you suggest `<li><a href="#tabs-2" runat="server" onserverclick="TodayTab_Click">Tomorrow</a></li>` and still not working

Comment: it is case sensitive write onServerClick

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend either using `<asp:linkbutton>` which has a serverside click event.  But then navigation will have to be handled in javascript by  manually navigating to the hashtag in the href. (I don't recommend this method as you don't need a full postback)

Keep in mind that this will do a full postback and will require an updatepanel if you don't want a full refresh.

Or continue using a standard hyperlink button, but have a pagemethod that handles the server side action you need and call it via ajax. I recommend this method as you stay 100% on the client as your server side needs only rely on posting very little data to the server.

Comment: i changed the a to `asp:Hyperlink` and still that code is not fired

Comment: Ah, my mistake.  There is no server side click event for a hyper link as it's action is all on the client.  The hyperlink never posts back to the server, so your code (as you have it) will never work.  You need to have a button that will postback to the server.

Comment: But i have to use `a` what should I do please?

Comment: It all depends on what you want to happen on the server.  The function you have is clearly just for testing purposes.  I would recommend using ajax.  Perhaps using pagemethods so you don't have to build an entire webservice for just one click.  Then on the client-side click event call the pagemethod and run whatever needs to be run on the server.

Comment: You can also use an `<asp:linkbutton />`, which looks like a link, but posts back to the server.  Keep in mind that this will cause a full postback so you may want to use an update panel and change the hash anchor in javascript.

Comment: Smeegs, I think you should delete this answer as the question is about posting back and running a function on the server side, not linking to another page. Thus, the asp:LinkButton is more appropriate, and freefaller already has that answer covered.

Comment: @mason, the conversation from this answer is valuable to anybody who comes across this post.  His answer can be the selected answer but there is still value to what's been said.  Although I can update my answer to make it reflect the discussion

Comment: Sorry, then I gotta downvote. Your answer is not related to the question, and I think will only confuse someone that's looking for an answer to the actual question asked.

Comment: @mason, as I said, I'll update my answer with the relevant information.  You can reserve your judgement at that point as I provide two solutions in my comment as the other answer doesn't fully solve the issue.

Comment: All I need is to save a parameter to know which tag, or you can say div, is being clicked.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect this conversation.  When you say save, do you mean to a database?

Comment: @mason, feel free to take a second look.

Comment: @mason, also a linkbutton would 100% break the tabbing functionality.

Comment: @user3432257, you never specified what you mean by "save a parameter" what do you eman?